Potential Memory Leak and Performance Concerns with CWinThread in MFC OnTimer Event
I am a new developer working with MFC, and I have a question about CWinThread. I have an OnTimer event that checks whether the position values of all axes are 0. Additionally, I have a function that verifies if the axis position is 0 or not, and this check can take up to 50 seconds for each axis. There are a total of 11 axes.
Currently, I am using a CWinThread function, which runs a loop that creates a thread for each axis. Once an axis's position is checked, the thread is deleted. I am calling this loop in the constructor of my dialog class, and the OnTimer function is also in the same dialog class.
My question is: when the loop executes inside OnTimer, it executes multiple times. Could this lead to memory leaks or affect the application's performance?
Note: The scenario only considers when the dialog opens.
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
      CheckHomeDone(i);
      Sleep(20);
}


UINT CMotionMovement::CheckHomeDoneThreadTemporary(LPVOID pParam)
{
    MachineSequence* pMachineSequence = reinterpret_cast<MachineSequence*>(pParam);

    pMachineSequence->motionParameters.HomeDone(t_nMotor);

    CWinThread* pThread = AfxGetThread();
    if (pThread != nullptr)  return delete pThread;

    return 0;
}

void CMotionMovement::CheckHomeDone(int motorID)
{
    t_nMotor = motorID;
    CWinThread* pThread = ::AfxBeginThread(CheckHomeDoneThreadTemporary, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);

    if (pThread != nullptr){
          pThread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;  
      pThread->ResumeThread();      
    }
    else{
      AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to create thread"), MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }
}

//Every 0.5 sec.
void CMotionMovement::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if(nIDEvent == MOTION_TIMER && bRunThread) {

        if(!bActiveTimer) {

            bActiveTimer = true;

            RedrawMotorPosStatus();

            if( moveMotorToNextVerificationPosition ) {
            
                moveVerificationMotor();

                linearEncoderPositionCounter = 0;
                verifyLinearEncoderPosition = true;
                displayEncoderVariation = false;

                moveMotorToNextVerificationPosition = false;
            }
            bActiveTimer = false;
        }
    }
    CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}

I need suggestions or solutions for how to update the details dialog properly without causing the dialog or application to freeze or hang.Thank you for your attention.

Some few issues: 1. Why set m_bAutoDelete to FALSE and finally delete the object yourself on termination? You could just just leave it to TRUE (default). Not sure if AfxGetThread() will return the same object you created. Not sure if the object can be deleted while the thread runs (you attempt to delete from within the thread proc). 2. You don't need to call ResumeThread(), as the thread wasn't created with the CREATE_SUSPENDED flag. 3. The threads you create are all passed the same parameter. They will all do the same job. 4. What is this in CheckHomeDone()? it is a free func,

Georgiou, thank you for your concern. CheckHomeDone() is a class member function, but I mistakenly removed the class name earlier. As for item 3, yes, it will perform the same job depending on the axis number.

@SDR AFAIU the for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) loop in in the dialog CMotionMovement constructor.  Please confirm and/or edit the question to make that clear. Anyway you probably should put the for loop into CMotionMovement::OnInitDialog().

Jabberwocky, CMotionMovement::OnInitDialog() is a large function that could cause more confusion, so I'll leave it as it is and let the loop execute as mentioned above.

Still, it is not OK. CheckHomeDone() creates 12 threads, but there is only one instance of t_nMotor (a member of CMotionMovement apparently). There should be one for each thread, that is, somehow passed to the thread via the parameter.

Georgiou, let's consider the t_nMotor class member in CMotionMovement before passing other values, as I mentioned earlier.   "pMachineSequence->motionParameters.HomeDone(t_nMotor);"

The more I look into it the more issues I find:

You are passing the threads the dialog object (this), but in the thread proc you cast it to MachineSequence. This is obviously wrong. You should rather pass a MachineSequence instance, each having its own t_nMotor member, as noted in the comments (and delete it, yes delete it, from the dialog class).
You mentioned that checks can take up to 50 secs to complete. However, you don't have some mechanism to prevent or postpone checks while the threads are running. You should rather wait for all threads to complete, before checking again (creating new threads). Don't know what your timer interval is though.
Does passing CheckHomeDoneThreadTemporary, ie a class member function, to AfxBeginThread() even compile? It takes a free function pointer.
Not sure if calls like moveVerificationMotor() should be performed in the context of the main or the worker threads. And if variables like moveMotorToNextVerificationPosition can be changed from the worker threads, you need synchronized access.

A more general note is that the technique you are using for checking, known as "polling" (ie periodically checking for data or conditions) has quite a few disadvantages. It should be employed only if it is otherwise impossible. If your API provides notifications, they should be preferred.
